# can genymotion be used to debug android apk with android studio

Tags: android

No matter how long I wait for Android Studio Emulator, it just won't run
can I use `Genymotion` or `VirtualBox` to debug an APK file and get the Trace output?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will work same way other emulators or real devices.

Comment: how can I bind or connect genymotion with android studio so that I can debug my application and read the trace output as with android studio AVDs

Comment: If Genymotion is running you shall see it as any other device. You may need to start Genymotion instance manually though.

Comment: thank you, it is working now Android studio identify genymotion

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use Genymotion with Android Studio.
Unfortunately, there isn't a Genymotion plugin for it, as it did in Eclipse, to make it easier to start the Virtual Device. But after the VD is running, you can choose it on the Run screen.

Edit:
There is a Genymotion plugin available. You can start the Genymotion Emulator in Android Studio.

Comment: That's not correcr,  there is such a plugin for AS

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I too using it.Log cat and everything works fine.